# Create new column populated with existing column name(s) conditional on values in existing column(s)

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have the following dataset:
`crab_traps <- tibble(trap_id = 1:5, logger_1 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), logger_2 = c(9, 7, 5, 3, 1), logger_3 = c(6, 5, 1, 7, 8)`
`trap_id` identifies a specific crab trap and each `logger_*` column is the distance to a water quality logger.
I want to create a new column (preferably using `dplyr::mutate`) to figure out which logger is closest to each trap.
Hopefully the new column would be something like `closest_logger <- c("logger_1", "logger_1", "logger_3", "logger_2", "logger_2")` (using this example data)
I have tried `crab_traps <- crab_traps %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(closest_logger = min(logger_1, logger_2, logger_3))` which gives me the smallest measurement, but I want to get the name of the column that the smallest measurement came from.
Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Try `names(crab_traps[-1])[max.col(-crab_traps[-1])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient solution would be using `max.col` :

```
crab_traps$closest_logger <- names(crab_traps)[max.col(-crab_traps[-1]) + 1]
```

---

If you want a `dplyr` solution you can try `c_across` with `rowwise`.

```
library(dplyr)

crab_traps %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(closest_logger = names(.)[which.min(c_across(starts_with('logger')))+1])

#  trap_id logger_1 logger_2 logger_3 closest_logger
#    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         
#1       1        2        9        6 logger_1      
#2       2        3        7        5 logger_1      
#3       3        4        5        1 logger_3      
#4       4        5        3        7 logger_2      
#5       5        6        1        8 logger_2
```

In both the cases, we add `+1` because we are ignoring the first column while calculating minimum.